# Opening a new terminal and executing command in it

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I wish to use a command in terminal that would open a new terminal and run command in that. Suppose I wish to run the "ls" command in new terminal, from the old. What should I do? Typing

```
gnome-terminal --ls
```

does not show the listed files in a new terminal as suggested in other questions. It does nothing, I get on output by running this command.

Comment: Spacing is important - the command suggested was probably `gnome-terminal -- ls`

Comment: you probably want gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'ls; bash'

Answer (score 0):

In your home directory is a hidden file named ".bashrc"
Open it with your favourite editor and add at the very end :

```
ls -la
```

Save it.
The next time you open a terminal it will list all the files in your directory. As ls -la is just an example, you could put any sensible command there